# How to use Events in vue-Carousel?

Tags: vue.js, carousel

I would like to navigate in my carousel using functions in methods.

I'm using this vue-carousel

[vue-carousel](https://github.com/SSENSE/vue-carousel)

They wrote in docs about events to navigate but i don't know how to use that. Any orientation ? Thank you!

Exemple :

```
methods: {
    GoToPage5:function(){
      //use Carousel events here    
    },
```

Comment: For me $refs is empty here. Did you do something else to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

As with any custom Vue component, you can bind [event listeners](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) using either the `v-on`, or the `@` shorthand:

```html
<carousel @navigation-click="navigationHandler">
```

then in your Vue configuration, you provide the handler method:

```js
{
  ...,

  methods: {
    navigationHandler(direction) {
      // direction = "backward" or "forward"
    }
  },
  
  ...
}
```

You can use the same convention to listen to any of the package's [custom events](https://github.com/SSENSE/vue-carousel#events).

---

**UPDATE:**

Since you're looking to make use of the `:navigate-to` property, you'll need to do the following:

1. Bind to the property correctly – using [kebab-case](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case) rather than camel-case:

```html
<carousel :navigate-to="manualNavigation">
```

2. Create the `manualNavigation` data property:

```js
{
  data() {
    return {
      ...
      manualNavigation: 5,
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

3. Manually update the `manualNavigation` property:

```js
{
  ...
  methods: {
    GoToPage5() {
      this.manualNavigation = 5;
    },
  }
}
```

Now, any time you call `GoToPage5()`, the carousel should respond by animating to your 5 slide.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, actually it's given my active slide index in console. but what I'm looking for it to navigateTo slide number 5 in example.  Isnt that possible ? 
:navigateTo="5" isn't working ...

Comment: Thank you for your update, i used this method but inavigate-to is not working on caorusel..

Comment: 6 , in props in carousel i have navigateTo=2 , but it's still oon slide 0

Comment: It's not 100% clear what the "navigate-to" prop is supposed to do, but it is imperative to write it as `:navigate-to="2"` rather than `:navigateTo="2"`. [Read here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case) for why. You can also see the [html structure example](https://github.com/SSENSE/vue-carousel#html-structure), and notice that they are using kebab case there.

Answer (score 0):

`:navigate-to="2"` seems not working in vue-carousel.

this code works.

```
         this.$refs.carousel.goToPage(2);
```

Comment: undefined ... If you need to move to the next slide via custom "next" button ... ?